# TD-W8951ND: Can I use this modem as router only?

Tags: router, ethernet, adsl

I am having a `modem / router` **TD-W8951ND** which works fine with ADSL cable (telephone cable). Since I am changing my broadband plan (they will be providing there own modem), I need to make wifi work with Ethernet cable as the source of internet.

I just want to know whether I can share my internet from ethernet cable to wifi using TD-W8951ND. If yes, how? I found a similar discussion here (not very conclusive) :-

http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1805509/link-w8951nd-150mbps-wireless-adsl2-modem-router-work-fiber-optic-gtpl-internet-broadband.html

Here is its User Manual:-

http://www.tp-link.in/resources/document/TD-W8951ND_V5_User_Guide_1910010890.pdf

Could anybody please tell me if its doable or not?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices and/or home networking are explicitly off-topic here. You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the new router that the provider will install has wifi?
From what I've read of the manual I'm not sure if this model is able to acquire or set an IP from/on a switch interface. If this is true, then what you want won't be doable.